# Is there a way to test a range of exponents in a lm() model in the same way as the code below more efficiently?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, modulo

The basic gist is that I have a set of housing data that I need to create a model for to minimize the predicted price vs actual price of house based on the dataset. So I created this bit of code to essentially test for a range of different numerators and find the one that minimized the difference between them. I'm using the median instead of the mean as the data isn't exactly normal.

Since I only have experience with lm(), I'm using that to create the coefficients and C values. But since the model likes exponents, I have to also test various exponents. It does this for each of the variables and then goes back to the first and re-evaluates it based on the other exponents. The model starts out with all the exponents ending up equal to 1. So the same as the basic linear model. I know that this is probably horribly inefficient and probably uses a lot of code in a somewhat wasteful, but I'm in my first r class so sorry about the mess and/or convoluted coding logic.

Is there any way to do this same thing but being more efficient. Also, I can't really decrease the number of variables as the model likes having more variables and produces a greater margin of error when they aren't present.

```
w <- seq(1,10000,1)
r <- seq(1,10000,1)
t <- seq(1,10000,1)
z <- seq(1,10000,1)
s <- seq(1,10000,1)
coef_1 <- c(6000,6000,6000,6000,6000,6000,6000,6000)
v <- rep(6000, each = 8)
for(l_1 in 1:10){
for(t_1 in 1:8){
for(i in 1:10000){
  t = t_1
  coef_1[t] = i
mod5 <- lm(log(SALE_PRC) ~ I(TOT_LVG_AREA^((coef_1[1]-5000)/1000)) + I(LND_SQFOOT^((coef_1[2]-5000)/1000)) + I(RAIL_DIST^((coef_1[3]-5000)/1000)) + I(OCEAN_DIST^((coef_1[4]-5000)/1000)) + I(CNTR_DIST^((coef_1[5]-5000)/1000)) + I(HWY_DIST^((coef_1[6]-5000)/1000)) + I(structure_quality^((coef_1[7]-5000)/1000)) + SUBCNTR_DI + SPEC_FEAT_VAL + (exp(((coef_1[8]-5000)/1000)*SPECIAL_RATIO)) + age, data = kaggle_transform_final)

kaggle_new <- kaggle_transform_final %>% 
  add_predictions(model = mod5, var = "prediction") %>% 
  mutate(new_predict = exp(prediction)) %>% 
  mutate(new_difference = abs((new_predict-SALE_PRC))/SALE_PRC) %>%
  mutate(average_percent_difference = median(new_difference)) %>% 
  mutate(mean_percent_difference = mean(new_difference)) %>%
  mutate(quart_75 = quantile(new_difference,.75))

  w[i] = kaggle_new$average_percent_difference[1]
  r[i] = kaggle_new$mean_percent_difference[1]
  t[i] = kaggle_new$quart_75[1]
  z[i] = i
  s[i] = (i-5000)/1000
  if(i%%100 ==0){show(i)}
}
  u <- data.frame(median_diff = w, mean_diff = r, quart_75 = t, actual = s, number = z) %>% 
    arrange(median_diff)
  
  coef_1[t_1] <- u$number[1]
  v[t_1] <- u$actual[1]
  show(coef_1)
}
  coef_1 <- coef_1
}
```

Comment: i don't really understand the question - are you trying to optimise both the exponents and the linear coefficients?

Comment: Both do to the fact that when I did either separately they produced larger percentiles. When I started out around the median of the absolute value of the difference between the models value and the actual sale price was around 21 percent. The model I found with the above code decreased that median is around 12.7 percent or 50 percent of the predicted values for the model that were within the absolute value of 12.7 percent.

Comment: So I am essentially using lm() to find the coeffients for the and the constant values but I found no way to do the same for the exponents in the same model. Hence the for loops repeatablely changing the exponents to produce a better model.